# JavaScript modal not opening on all pages

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener

I have created a JavaScript modal that opens on click it's isolated in one file and I want to reuse it on other pages, it works fine on the index.html page, but when I want to use it on another page it gives me `Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` I tried wrapping my js modal code in a window.onload = function() {} because I believed that the DOM had not been loaded fully but again it didn't work, how can I make it work on every page?

here is the index.html content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/modal.css">
  <title>Word Spelling Game</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="menu">
      <audio controls autoplay loop>
          <source src="./sounds/menu-song.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
          Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
    <a href="./pages/game-menu.html">
      <img src="./images/choose-game-sign.png" class="board"> 
    </a>
    <div>
    <img src="./images/help-sign.png" class="board trigger">
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close-button">&times;</span>
           <h1>Welcome!</h1>
           <article>
             This is a collection of interactive games designed for children, each game
             aims to further develop the childs skill set in a variety of tasks that involve
             spelling, writing and simple math. It is designed in a fun way so that your kid will never become bored!
             There are different levels of difficulty for different ages. To select and play
             a level click on the Choose level tab above this one. You can see each game's rules
             by clicking on the rules tab that is located on the right corner on each level. The instructions are written in 
             a way that every kid can understand in case that he get's stuck at some point.
           </article>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="./scripts/help-modal.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The other page on which I want to use it that the user reaches after he clicks the Choose Game link:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css//game-menu.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/modal.css">
  <script src="../scripts/help-modal.js"></script>
  <title>Levels</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="../index.html">
  <img src="../images/back-sign.png">
  </a>
  <div class="help">
      <p class="question-mark">?</p>
      <div class="modal">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <span class="close-button">&times;</span>
             <h1>Welcome!</h1>
             <article>
               This is a collection of interactive games designed for children, each game
               aims to further develop the childs skill set in a variety of tasks that involve
               spelling, writing and simple math. It is designed in a fun way so that your kid will never become bored!
               There are different levels of difficulty for different ages. To select and play
               a level click on the Choose level tab above this one. You can see each game's rules
               by clicking on the rules tab that is located on the right corner on each level. The instructions are written in 
               a way that every kid can understand in case that he get's stuck at some point.
             </article>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my help-modal.js file:

```
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
    var trigger = document.querySelector(".trigger");
    var closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");

    function toggleModal() {
        modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
    }

    function windowOnClick(event) {
        if (event.target === modal) {
            toggleModal();
        }
    }

    trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
    closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
    window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
```

Answer (score 2):

On your second HTML file you seem to not have any element with `trigger` class. This is the reason for your error in Console.

Including your JavaScript files in the end of `body`(just how you did in your `intex.html`) is also a good practice, in order to make sure that JavaScript will run after all HTML elements were loaded.

Answer (score 1):

1) On the "other" page, move the `<script>` tag to the bottom of the markup, like it is in the "index" page, or add a `window.onload = function() {}` wrapper around the code in the .js file.

The reason for this is that currently in the "other" page, the script is loading first. When it loads, it is immediately executed by the browser. So it immediately runs `var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");`. However, since the script was loaded before any of the HTML in the `<body>`, there is no element available which matches the selector `.modal`. So nothing is selected, and consequently the event listeners are not attached to any element, and so are never triggered.

2) Added to that, your "other" page doesn't contain any element with the class "trigger". So even once you fix the loading issue, the line `var trigger = document.querySelector(".trigger");` will still not select anything, and you'll still get a similar error when it tries to attach an event handler to nothing. So you need to correct that too. (This will be why your earlier attempt at `window.onload = function() {}` failed).

In summary - the HTML elements you're targeting must exist before the JavaScript you're using to target them is executed.